# Does Python execute code from the top or bottom of the script

Tags: python

I am working on learning Python and was wondering in what way the scripts are executed what i mean like this if Python runs the code from the beginning of the script or the bottom

Comment: That is very easy to find out, isn't it?

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow it is expected that the person asking a question has done his/her best to find a solution to the problem already and present what has been tried. You on the other hand have asked a question that can be solved with no more effert than running two lines of code.

Comment: @Joe From the top of the file.

Comment: My response was deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the things at the top will be read first so for example if you create a function at the top and execute it at the bottom your script will work fine.

But if you execute the function first and then define it at the bottom when python gets to execute the function it will not know what you are trying to execute.

This will work

```
def myFunction():
    print "Hello World!"

myFunction()
```

This will not work (because python doesn't know what myFunction() is because it hasn't seen it before:

```
myFunction()

def myFunction():
    print "Hello World!"
```

Comment: So if all of my code is separated inside of different functions would i need a piece of code at the bottom or the top to call the main function that will call the others based  on the flow of the program execution?

Comment: @Joe Yes, you always need a piece of code to start the program running. If not you are only saving the functions to memory but never using them :)
And it will always have to be at the bottom, if it's at the top it will fail.

Comment: Sorry one more question about something related to this so Python executes from top to bottom but what about if statements that don't have a else attached are they ignored or does execution just keep on going after the if statement again sorry for the noob questions

Answer (score 0):

Code executes on the main scope from top to bottom. If you have several functions in the bottom that are being defined but not called and then code in the main scope below them, it would run the code. However, everything that is in the same scope is ran from top to bottom.

```
def function_1():
   returns 3
x = 6 
y = 1
# x = 6 is executed first and the y, function is not called here.
```

if you do the below, function_1/p assignment gets executed first, then x then y assignments

```
def function_1():
   returns 3
p = function_1()
x = 6
y = 1
```

This can be expanded into several answers but you will understand more how the script executes through examples. I would recommend to try things locally and learn by doing. Good luck!

Comment: So it does not execute the function first but executes the other code? I'm still confused

Comment: You can think of a scope as a level. If you have a function, the code inside the function is like one level down. This code is never called except if it is called on level 0 (the main level), by calling the function. On all levels, if the code is called, it executes from top to bottom. On level 0 (the main level or the main function if you have one) the code is always executed.

Comment: What do you mean by main level? Sorry just new to all of this and the reason i ask is because when i'm writing Python code my script sometimes throws errors with variables later on such as not being defined but i solve it by using a global variable instead of a local ( Outside of function )